# IE bug with min-width?

Tags: html, css

I have given a div a min-width , and a percentage width . It seems to be working as expected on Chrome and FF , but in IE ( 7 & 9 ) , the min-width is not enforced . The following code illustrates the behaviour in t.

```
<div style="background-color:#fc0;min-width:500px; width:10%;">
test
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `min-width` attribute is supported in IE 7 and later, but only if you have a strict doctype.

Ref: [min-width Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530820%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet for simulating min-height in IE5+. It should be useful for what you want to do.

I guess it'll probably work for width changing the auto for whatever value you want.

```
height: auto!important; /* for good browsers */ 
height: 175px; /* for IE5+ */ 
min-height: 175px; /* for good browsers */
```